# Replace whitespace with comma between certain tags in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm trying to write a regex in notepad++ that takes all whitespaces contained between 2 tags and replace them with comma.

So basically, if I have this input:

```
<foo>bar bar bar</foo>
<tag>bar bar bar</tag>
```

And I want to replace whitespaces only inside foo tags to get a resut:

```
<foo>bar,bar,bar</foo>
<tag>bar bar bar</tag>
```

Matching everything between foo is fairly straightforward:

```
(?<=(<foo>))(.*)(?=(<\/foo>))
```

But searching for \s doesn't work:

```
(?<=(<foo>))(\s)(?=(<\/foo>))
```

Comment: Try `(?:\G(?!^)|<foo>)[^ <]*\K\s+` --> `,`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Hyq0Nm/1).

Comment: Thank you Wiktor, post your answer as a comment so I can accept it.

Comment: Or by just a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html): [`\s(?=[^<]*</foo)`](https://www.regex101.com/r/Bz8SoK/2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you want to replace the spaces inside tags that has no children, nor the same nested tags, you may use

```
(?:\G(?!^)|<foo>)[^\s<]*\K\s+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Hyq0Nm/2), replace with `,`.

**Details**:

- `(?:\G(?!^)|<foo>)`  - either the end of the previous successful match or `<foo>`
- `[^\s<]*` - zero or more symbols other than whitespace and `<`
- `\K` -  omit the text matched so far
- `\s+` - 1 or more whitespaces.

Comment: how to make it work in Javascript/python?

Comment: @uingtea JS: `text.replace(/<foo>[\w\W]*?<\/foo>/g, function(x) { return x.replace(/\s+/g, ',') })` and Python `re.sub(r'(?s)<foo>.*?</foo>', lambda x: re.sub(r'\s+', ',', x.group()), text)`

Comment: can it done without callback or there are no equivalent `\G` or `\K` in JS?

Comment: @uingtea Neither `\G`, nor `\K` are available in JS `RegExp` and Python `re`. In Python, though, this regex will work with the PyPi `regex` library: `import regex` and then `regex.sub(r'(?:\G(?!^)|<foo>)[^\s<]*\K\s+', ',', text)`